# Is it possible to assign job names to separate workers in a SLURM array via sbatch?

Tags: slurm

By default, when submitting a SLURM job as an array, all jobs within the array share the same job name.  In the docs (here: https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html), it shows that each job in the array can have its name set separately via `scontrol` (described under the section "Scontrol Command Use").

Can this be done directly from an `sbatch` script?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this in the meantime? I'm also interested in this question.

Comment: @JohannesAckermann Unfortunately I did not.

Answer (score 0):

I just created an account because I was trying to do this and I did find a solution.
You can use scontrol to change the name of a job, the syntax is the following:

```
scontrol update job=<job_id> JobName=<new_name>
```

You can do this manually, but you can also automatically set the name of the job from within the array job, thus automatically assigning a different name to each job in the array.

I find this useful because I'm mostly running calculations in different directories and if I have one job running much longer than the others I want to be able to quickly retrieve where it's running to see what's going on.
Of course you could set other things as your job name, as you prefer.

In my case, I add the scontrol command to the script I run through the array in order to obtain the following name for each directory: "job_name - directory". The job id and job name can be retrieved from environment variables.

```
scontrol update job=$SLURM_JOB_ID JobName="$SLURM_JOB_NAME - $folder"
```

EDIT: I updated the command as suggested by jordi, I had it correct in my script but apparently copied the wrong variable while replying here.

Comment: This doesn't quite work because SLURM_ARRAY_JOB_ID is the id of the parent job and renames all jobs in the array to have the exact same name. Need to use job=$SLURM_JOB_ID instead.